# Crash while executing python script via c++ program

Tags: python, c++, windows, codeblocks

i'm using code::blocks v16.01 on windows 10.
trying to execute a python script i wrote (v3.7.3) from my c++ program through the python api.

i can see the script does run independently, but running from the c++ program, the thread does not return to continue and got lost on the way and stuck on the python executing line "PyRun_SimpleFile(file, Xi_Path.c_str());" with a segmentation fault.

i can see the python script works since it suppose to change a xml file and it does change.

this is the code i use:

```
Py_SetProgramName(l_path);
Py_Initialize();
PySys_SetArgv(5, wargs);
FILE* file = fopen(Xi_Path.c_str(),"rb+");
PyRun_SimpleFile(file, Xi_Path.c_str());
Py_Finalize();
```

tried to change the "rb+" to "r+", no change. 
same error while using the python v2.7

i encountered this documentation from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html) which might shed some light:

**"Note also that several of these functions take FILE* parameters. One particular issue which needs to be handled carefully is that the FILE structure for different C libraries can be different and incompatible. Under Windows (at least), it is possible for dynamically linked extensions to actually use different libraries, so care should be taken that FILE* parameters are only passed to these functions if it is certain that they were created by the same library that the Python runtime is using."**

but i'm not sure i understood the meaning.

any suggestions please?

Comment: *but i'm not sure i understood the meaning.* -- What exactly in the **bold** text is not understood?  The `FILE` structure in a C or C++ program is not guaranteed to have the same internals between compilers, and even between the same compilers.  You can't even mix `FILE` types within C or C++ programs, let alone Python.  If a C++ program compiled with compiler A takes a `FILE*` as an argument, and a C++ program compiled with compiler B (or even compiler A using different compilation options) passes a `FILE *` to the function, then all bets are off as to what will happen.

Comment: The upshot of what @PaulMcKenzie is (correctly) saying is; *all* code in a program (the main executable, libraries it is linked with, libraries it loads, etc) should, as a general rule (there *are* exceptions where binary compatibility is preserved), all be compiled with the *exact same* C++ compiler using the *exact same* compiler options/flags.

Comment: Did you rey running a simple dummy script that only prints something? Could you also post the script, and also the commands used to build the code? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **Also**: you didn't test *fopen* result for *NULL* before using it, which is a perfect candidate for *segfault*s.